# .gitignore and untracked files are shown in git status

Tags: git, gitignore, git-status, git-untracked

I am getting wierd scenario on Centos 7.5.1804 with git 1.8.3.1.
I have `.gitignore` as

```
*.pyc
```

but `git status` showing following

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   a.pyc
#   b.pyc
#   c.pyc
#   d.pyc
```

Also, those files have never been committed. So **git status** should not have shown those files. What could cause this to happen?

Comment: Where is the gitignore file in relation to these files?

Comment: All files in same folder which is root of git directory.

Comment: That's odd. I can't replicate this... I'm using centos `7.5.1804` (docker image), git-x86-64 `1.8.3.1-20.el7`. Can you make sure that there is no whitespace around `*.pyc` in the gitignore file?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Awesome. You are right. It was due to whitespace only. However, I am using the same files in Ubuntu 16.04.5 with git 2.7.4 which didn't show those files. So I got confused.

Comment: Fab! Glad you found the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a typo in the .gitignore file which had extra space after `*.pyc`. However, the behaviour was different on `Ubuntu 16.04.5` with `git 2.7.`4 where the files were not listed even with extra space.

Probably this space issue has been taken cared between `git 1.8.3.1` and `2.7.4`.

Comment: Note that the [current documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) mentions it: `Trailing spaces are ignored unless they are quoted with backslash ("\").`